# Copy Range of Multiple Colums and post into another worksheet within same document in VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

What Im trying to to is take information from row C,D,E,F,F,AL,AM from Sheet Add all the at information starts on Row 3 and put it into Sheet Final Data and start on Row 3.
Is there a way to write a VBA script for it?

Comment: Yes, if you open VBE (Visual Basic Editor) window (perhaps using Alt-F11) then you can start writing a script there.  Once written, you will be able to invoke that script whenever you like.

Comment: OK, that was a bit tongue-in-cheek, but you really need to show what code you are having trouble with if you expect us to be able to assist you to get it working.

Comment: start by recording a macro